# Gerrit: Can I specify reviewer (-2 ... +2) commit thresholds per directory?

Tags: prolog, gerrit

I'm configuring a Gerrit server for code review. I'd like an explicitly-specified subdirectory in the repo (say, `/experimental`), where code reviews aren't required.

If a user is trying to push a patch set that **only** consists of changes to `/experimental/...`, they shouldn't need any +1 / +2 from peers. Otherwise, they need a total +2 and no -2's to merge to master.

Similarly, we might have extremely safety-critical code organized under a specific folder. In that folder we might need +4 and **no** negative scores to move forward.

These types of configurations doesn't seem possible from the web UI; does it require custom Prolog, or an entirely new custom plugin?

If there is a Prolog path, how do I iterate over the files in the requested merge to test their paths?

Comment: Of interest: [Gerrit Code Review - Prolog Submit Rules Cookbook](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, none of the examples do any work against the files in the patch set. I'm starting to think that it has to be a custom Java plugin.

Comment: The link was not for you, but for me and others who are not aware of the relationship between Gerrit and Prolog. I was thinking the Prolog tag was a mistake but did some checking as I have never seen Gerrit before. When I found the referenced page I knew the Prolog tag was not a mistake. So to keep others from removing the Prolog tag thinking the same, I added the link.